# Weekly Digest of changes to SharePoint Documents?

Tags: list, document-library, email, alert, information-management

I want to be able to get a daily email notifying me of changes to certain libraries that I select.

So what I was thinking is to set an alert for each library that I am interested in receiveing updates from, and selecting the daily summary option. Now this works nicely BUT I receive a separate email from each of those libraries I have alerts on. Is there any OOTB way to receive a summary off the libraries in one email? Are there non-OOTB solutions? And are alerts a good way of doing this?

Thanks! (I am using SP 2010 server)

Comment: anyone have any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the Box:

If you can find a search term that will give you all of the libraries you should be able to set an alert for that search and have it send you alerts when changes happen in those results.

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it is the tool MS gave us for not attaching to a list.

Custom:

This could be a rabbit hole. Before tackling this method, I would work real hard on trying to make the search results solution work for you including changing names or adding custom data to make very specific searches possible.

Create a workflow that grabs all of the changes from the Site collection like in this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408275/using-getchanges-in-sharepoint-sitedata-web-service

Then filter the changes based on the required doc libraries. Then have the workflow email you the results.